# Mail feature on SO :O

Tags: feature-request

I was wondering if SO could have a mailing feature. Yes it is not a social site, but then there are times, when a piece of code is just too large, or when a portion of code alone may not be shared, because its interlinked with other classes. It really becomes easy sharing a file to a single user or may b multiple through mails instead of dumping code on pastebin. I don't know if thats a valid reason really to have a mail feature, but it's  worth it. What say ?

Comment: No, it's not a valid reason. I doubt users really want their inboxes filled with random code samples for questions.

Comment: Even more: sending code to some email address is not helping future visitors of these sites. And *all* questions should have some value for future visitors.

Comment: yes, both of you are true. With so many minus votes, why is the question not closed ?

Comment: @Arjan except in [codegolf.se], it's the question that has a lasting value, not its answers :-)

Comment: @DharaShah why close it? It _is_ a feature request. It's just 100% unpopular

Comment: But you can delete it yourself, @Dhara, if you don't want this feature anymore.

Comment: @DharaShah On meta, downvoting usually just mean that we disagree. Your feature-itself is still a valid feature-request and I can not think of any reason to close it.

Comment: i faced this issue cz i wanted to share an apk just to check if its the code with an issue or what, cz there was a confusion as to whats really wrong. :) .. alright, i dont mind it remaining open

Comment: @Arjan i choose to keep it.. :) .

Comment: If you want to discuss some code in private (unrelated to the question), you can establish a private connection through other means already.

Comment: very true sir .. :)

Comment: Close votes would mean we think it was wrong to ask this; **we do not think that**, however we do disagree

Answer (score 7):

People who are willing to get email from those who know them on SO can and do put their email addresses in their profiles. If someone does that, you can use any mechanism you like (Eg copy and paste to your mail client) to send them an email.

People who don't want to get email from those who know them on SO don't put their email addresses in their profiles, and might go so far as to leave the site if it made it easy for them to be emailed against their will.

Any question that is asked and answered one-on-one through email is a question that doesn't appear publicly on the site and doesn't get a chance to make the internet better.

In sum, there are at least two things to be lost if this feature was implemented, and nothing to be gained. You can be confident it will not be implemented.

Comment: :) true it is and SO is a place where knowledge sharing takes place

Answer (score 3):

If your piece of code if too big for a direct question on Stack Overflow then your scope of the question is too wide.

We want question to the point here with very specific code segments describing only the exact problem. Don't push code in a question to ask for finding the error in the needlestack.

If you ask a question then do your homework, reduce it to the core problem. That way the question can be helpful for future visitors having the same problem and not just you.

So we don't need a email feature for too big code samples.

Comment: true, thanks to some of the SO questions posted here, i do google and then post in a question but it so happens that sometimes we end up facing things that no one really has, and the question never gets any answer, esp whn it comes to dealing with threads its never known as to wether its a device's processor that fails or the code:)